# How to use the word "inutile"?

Tags: word-usage

Definition of *inutile* by [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inutile):

> **ADJECTIVE**
>   ***formal***
>   Useless; pointless.

I can't find any example sentences of its usage. How can I use the word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it as any other **adjective** is used. "**inutile**" means '*lacking in utility or serviceability*':

- *You have a lot of **inutile** discussion here.*
- *This paper hammer is **inutile**.*
- *It is an **inutile** article.*

However, notice that the word is so rare that almost nobody uses it. Some dictionaries point out that it is obsolete or archaic. Use "**useless**" and "**pointless**" instead.

Comment: so how does *useless* or *pointless* differ from ***inutile***?

Comment: @XPMai They are more common.

Comment: yeahh, but I want a more *technical* answer. :P

Comment: @XPMai Then consult a bigger dictionary or try English Language and Usage SE. If there is a difference, it's not of interest to most learners since the only relevant observation is "don't say *inutile*". (It's rate enough that I would be surprised to find many people who could read it aloud without hesitating on the pronunciation... myself included.) But FWIW, I don't think this is a case of subtle differences so much as artificial vocabulary expansion that didn't take on.